# iOS | Layout constraint error when adding two views programatically

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, autolayout

I have a piece of code to display image view and UILabel side by side.It displays as expected based on the constraints provided but there a lot of warnings in the console

Here is the error

```
[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
Try this: 
    (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
    (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000003d0190 V:|-(0)-[UIImageView:0x7faa7401b940]   (active, names: '|':Movies_TODO.MovieViewCell:0x7faa7402caa0'custom' )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000003d05a0 UIImageView:0x7faa7401b940.bottom == Movies_TODO.MovieViewCell:0x7faa7402caa0'custom'.bottom   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000003d0640 UIImageView:0x7faa7401b940.height == 100   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000003e7070 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' Movies_TODO.MovieViewCell:0x7faa7402caa0'custom'.height == 100.5   (active)>"
)
```

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint

Here is my piece of my code

```swift
self.addSubview(movieImageView)
self.addSubview(titleLabel)

movieImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
movieImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
movieImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
movieImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true

movieImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true

titleLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: movieImageView.trailingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
titleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
titleLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
titleLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `movieImageView` has a constraint like `height equal to 100` AND `height equal to super view's height` (this come from since you added top and bottom anchor constraints).

---

1 - If you want to set `movieImageView` from top to bottom just delete `movieImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true`.

---

2 - If you want to set `movieImageView`'s height constantly 100 just delete the line you don't want to set for the `movieImageView` ->

```swift
// if you want to stick your imageView to bottom delete this
movieImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true

// if you want to stick your imageView to top delete this
movieImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

---

**With `UIStackView`**

- If you want to create a `TableViewCell` has left sided image and right sided label, you can use `StackView` and you can do what you want without any constraints.

**Create a `UIStackView`**

```swift
let stackView = UIStackView()
```

**Add your `movieImageView` and `titleLabel`**

```swift
stackView.addArrangedSubviews(movieImageView, titleLabel)
stackView.axis = .horizontal
stackView.spacing = 20.0
```

**Add your `stackView` to `super.view`**

```swift
self.addSubview(stackView)
stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

stackView. trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self. trailingAnchor).isActive = true
stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
```

**If you want to set `movieImageView`'s width from it's image, you should set `Content Hugging Priority` of the `movieImageView`**

```swift
movieImageView.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .horizontal)
```

**If you want to set `titleLabel`'s width from it's text and resistant than the imageView, you should set `Compression Resistance Priority` of the `titleLabel`**

```swift
titleLabel.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultHigh, for: .horizontal)
```

---

**BONUS**

[Intrinsic Content Size](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/what-is-a-views-intrinsic-content-size)

[UIStackView Guide](https://medium.com/the-traveled-ios-developers-guide/uistackview-a-field-guide-c1b64f098f6d)

[UIStackView Example of Hackingwithswift](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/31/2/uistackview-by-example)

Comment: if I remove any of the constraints, the view is getting distorted. Btw, This goes as a table view cell

Comment: The size of the image is huge and that is distorting the view even when added in a stackview.How do i contain the image size to a particular width and height

Comment: if I add height constraint and remove bottom anchor to stack view, the view is still distorted

Comment: your question was about constraint errors, please ask another question about your UI after made some research about (stackView) or your UI related issues. please consider this: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .

Answer (score 2):

You have set the bottom anchor and top anchor of your movieImageView which indirectly saying the height of your movieImageView.

After setting the height already you again changing your height to some constant value 100.

To avoid this warning remove

```
movieImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

This warning is because of redundant constraints for same property.

You try the bellow constraints

```
    movieImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
    movieImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    movieImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    movieImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true

    titleLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: movieImageView.trailingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    titleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
    titleLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    titleLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.movieImageView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

The result of this constraints is

[image: Result of the constraints]

Comment: if I remove any of the constraints, the view is getting distorted. Btw, This goes as a table view cell